# R for loop counter variable remains in global environment

Tags: r, for-loop, scope, global-variables, local-variables

In R, why does the `j` variable defined in the below for-loop remain in the global environment/scope after the loop execution.

```
for (j in 1:2){
  print(j)
}
```

Screenshot of terminal window with code execution where you see the variables in the global environment before and after the for loop execution.

[image]

Comment: Because that's how it is implemented and documented. See `help("for")`: "When the loop terminates, var remains as a variable containing its latest value."

Comment: Explicitly wrap it in local if you want to contiain the j:  `local( for(j in 1:2) print(j) )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a design choice.  If you look at the documentation

```
?`for`
```

It says

> When the loop terminates, var remains as a variable containing its
>   latest value.

I expect that is so that if you jump out of the loop, say with `last()` you can know which index you were on.